# How can I check if an attribute exist in XmlAttributeCollection?

Tags: c#, xmlattributecollection

I was checking [XmlNode.Attributes topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx) on MSDN about methods for checking if a `XmlNode` an attribute exists given its name. Well, there is no sample on how to check an item.

I have something like:

```
  //some code here...

  foreach (XmlNode node in n.SelectNodes("Cities/City"))
  {
        //is there some method to check an attribute like
        bool isCapital = node.Attributes.Exist("IsCapital");

        //some code here...
  }
```

So, what would be the best approach to check if an attribute exist or not in each node?
Is it ok to use `node.Attribute["IsCapital"]!=null` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use the indexer - if the attribute doesn't exist, the indexer returns `null`:

```
bool isCapital = nodes.Attributes["IsCapital"] != null;
```

This is documented on [`XmlAttributeCollection.ItemOfProperty (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b823yx9.aspx).

> The `XmlAttribute` with the specified name. If the attribute does not exist, this property returns `null`.

Comment: Seems inapplicable for boolean attributes which can be present but have no value specified. like `<myTag text="something" isChecked />`

Comment: @Ivan - you seem to be thinking about HTML, not XML. XML does not allow attributes that do not have values in them.

Comment: But what about XHTML, @Oded? Isn't it meant to be valid XML while allowing attributes without values for booleans? I actually seek to use this in my own XML for "debloat" purpose.

Comment: @Ivan - No. XHTML has to be valid XML too - that's the whole point of it. It doesn't allow boolean attributes.

Comment: For practical use, keep in mind that `XmlNode.Attributes` property can be null.  `nodes?.Attributes["IsCapital"] != null`